# Using Vagrant for customizable Wordpress Multi-sites

Tags: plugins, customization, multisite, database

### **Background:**

My partner and I have a goal to create a customizable vagrant project that uses Wordpress multi site, as a local development environment.

---

**Ideal Use Case:** Various developers on our team (of varying skill levels) will be provided with a vagrant package. When they "vagrant-up" they should be provided a standard lamp stack containing a multi-site wordpress instance. Any resources they need are included in the process of provisioning, including the database, plugins, themes, uploads-file's. Support for grunt.js task-running is available. They can proceed to develop, and have an easy option for Version Control.

---

**The Reality (our challenges):**

While there are many options available for using vagrant and a standard wordpress.org installation, we have not yet found a workable solution or adaptation. We have encountered these problems:

**1. Wordpress Mult-site needs to be on port 80.** so rather than using Port forwarding ([vagrant docs](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/networking/forwarded_ports.html)), we opted for [private network](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/networking/private_network.html), in addition to [synced folders](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/).

**2. Hosts files.** There are several nice plugins that we have experimented with that allow us to edit the hosts file on the host-machine side [Vagrant hosts manager](https://github.com/smdahlen/vagrant-hostmanager) and [vagrant host updater](https://github.com/cogitatio/vagrant-hostsupdater). In windows host machines, it was necessary for permissions to be changed  to prevent UAC from preventing the the updating.

**3. The database** We have used options that exist in [puphpet](https://puphpet.com/) to experiment using SQL import as part of the provisioning process. Also, we have tried using a wordpress plugin that we are familiar with, [migrate DB Pro](https://deliciousbrains.com/wp-migrate-db-pro/).Our purpose with Migrate DB PRo was just to make the database connection work. Both my partner and myself are not able access sub-directories (rather we receive a file not found error)

These are some of our major hurdles, there may be more details, but for the moment I would like to focus on the question at hand.

---

---

### **The Question:**

There is no single question to capture what I hope to convey, but please consider the following:

Do you have any successful experiences in implementing a WordPress multi-site? If so, how did you overcome some of the common pitfalls? Did you rely upon an existing source or process model? Where do I seem to be failing in my approach?

Comment: I don't have much to say other than provisioning workflow problems with WP start and end with the DB. It makes working with modern tools difficult. You can write your own DB migration scripts but they tend to be not very flexible and a pain in the arse to manage.

Comment: Please do **not** use the [tag:php] tag. That could be thrown on nearly any question. Thanks. About your question: Can you please rework it so that it is answerable?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the [Genesis-Wordpress](https://github.com/genesis/wordpress)(Note: not the framework) project for this. It does more or less what you have described above including,

- Provisioning (with Ansible)
- Deployment (with Capistrano)
- Database Synchronization (with custom Capistrano tasks)

It also uses the [Vagrant Host Manager](https://github.com/genesis/wordpress) to workaround the `/etc/hosts` issue. So the site is served over port 80.

Adding `WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE` to your `wp-config.php` should give you multisite support.

`define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );`

Answer (score 0):

You should look into Bedrock:
roots.io/wordpress-stack/

Sounds like it'd be a good starting point for you. roots.io is, IMO, as good as it gets for  theme development. I've used it for some time now and at the point where I know Bedrock would be a far better workflow - is a little daunting though so love to know how you get on.

In terms of multisite specifically I've used the Bitnami WP multisite stacks in the past, didn't really fit for me and don't think it would with your preference for Vagrant, but another option for others and very easy to set up.
bitnami.com/stack/wordpress/installer

For multisite specific info wpmudev.org is the place.

Apologies I can't post actual links.